# Failed to proxy the request :8080, because the request to the proxy target failed

Tags: .net, vue.js, asp.net-core

I tried to use this template:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexandredotnet.vuejsdotnetfive

But after build (it adds a lot of files/folders) and run it I get this error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico, because the request to the proxy target failed. Check that the proxy target server is running and accepting requests to http://localhost:8080/.

The underlying exception message was 'An error occurred while sending the request.'.Check the InnerException for more details.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: En etablert tilkobling ble avbrutt av programvaren på vertsmaskinen..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): En etablert tilkobling ble avbrutt av programvaren på vertsmaskinen.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My problem now is that I have no idea how to proceed as I dont understand much about the error with proxy.
Is the error that port 8080 is busy? Then what is using it? Should I redirect to another port? Should I free :8080?
The template recipie does not say I have to do anything.

So my goal is to run this and have the Core and Vue.js run together.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird, and I have no explanation, but my application only works in Chrome, not in Edge, which I started with.

Just wanted to post the solution, if any other person came by this.